# Track the number of objects created via the default constructor in Java

Tags: java

My goal is to print out the number of Complex objects (which should be 2) but my main method doesn't seem to accept my defObjCount class. What am I supposed to do so it counts the Complex objects?

```
public class Complex {
    private double a = 0; // real numbers
    private double b = 0; // imaginary numbers
    private static int counter = 0;

    public Complex(double a, double b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        counter++;
    }

    public void defObjCount(){
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

    public boolean equals(Complex rhs){
        return a == rhs.a && b == rhs.b;
    }

    public Complex multiply(Complex rhs){
        return new Complex(a * rhs.a - b * rhs.b, b * rhs.a + a * rhs.b);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%.0f + %.0fi", a, b);
    }
}
```

main class:

```
public class ComplexDriver{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Complex c1 = new Complex(1,2);
        Complex c2 = new Complex(3, 4);

        System.out.println(c1);
        //boolean same = c1.equals(c2);
        //Complex prod = c2.multiply(c1);
        System.out.println(c1.equals(c2));
        System.out.println(c1.equals(c1));
        System.out.println(c1.multiply(c1));
        System.out.println(c2.multiply(c2));

        System.out.println("Number of Complex obj created: " + Complex.defObjCount());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make your method `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that `defObjectCount` is declared `void`, which means that it doesn't have a return value that you can use anywhere.  It also needs to be `static` so that you can use it without calling it on a particular object.  You'd be better off writing it like this.

```
public static int defObjCount(){
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: After correcting my code in your way, it displays: "Number of Complex... " = 4 instead of a 2. Is there any other problem in my code that doesnt make me get the number of objects i want?

Comment: 4 seems correct to me.  You've got `c1`, `c2`, plus the two that you make with the two calls to `multiply`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `defObjCount()` method is simply printing, NOT returning anything. You can change it's return type to `int` and return your counter variable instead of printing it (as mentioned in David's answer).

Apart from that, you can also do something like this:

```
System.out.println("Number of Complex obj created: ");
c1.defObjCount(); //or c2.defObjCount();
```

`c1.defObjCount()` would be printing 4.